# Installing Agda on windows

Tags: installation, windows-installer, agda

I have been trying to install Agda on Windows 10. I have installed all the prerequisites (GHS, Cabal, Alex, Happy from Haskell Package and Emacs). I entered

```
cabal install Agda
```

It installed a lot of things, but it got stuck on Agda. So I redid the above command and got the same error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - Agda-2.6.1 (lib:Agda, exe:agda, exe:agda-mode) (requires build)
Starting     Agda-2.6.1 (all, legacy fallback)
Building     Agda-2.6.1 (all, legacy fallback)
cabal.exe: Failed to build Agda-2.6.1. The build process terminated with exit
code -1073740791
```

How should I progress?

Comment: Maybe out of memory.  Did you watch the memory consumption?  How many GB of free memory did you have when you tried it?